# Is there a characterization of contractible hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, affine-geometry

Let $V$ be an irreducible, algebraic hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is contractible as a topological space. I would like to know the algebraic characterization of such objects. For example, restriction, if any, on the degree of the defining polynomial.
What happens in higher-dimensions ?

Comment: For smooth algebraic curve, affine means projective with finite points removed. The contractible is equivalent with 0 genus and one point removed.

Comment: I am interested in knowing if there is a characterization of polynomials whose vanishing set is contractible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Belanov says in the comments above, this is relatively easy to decide for curves, since the only contractible complex algebraic curve is $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$. If the (irreductible) curve is not smooth, then it is contractible iff its semi-normalisation is $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$. This shows that there will be contractible singular curves of arbitrary high degree (take $y^2=x^{2k+1}$ for any $k\geq 1$) , but that for smooth curves any degree beyond $2$ will yield a non-contractible curve.

On the other hand, the analoguous problem for surfaces is difficult and has been studied quite a bit. A beautiful theorem along those lines is due to Ramanujam (1971): a smooth complex algebraic surface which is contractible and "simply connected at infinity" is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$. See this [survey](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~ars/cpr1.pdf) for more information about this theorem and subsequent developments.

Comment: Thanks. Will you suggest some reference where the topology of such singular curves is discussed? I am particularly interested in knowing whether $(\mathbb{C}^2, C)\cong (\mathbb{R}^4, \mathbb{R}^2)$, where $C$ is a singular, contractible curve.

Comment: No, in general, the topology of the complement will be very different from the topology of $\mathbb{C}^*$, essentially because of a large fundamental group. The basic reference is Milnor's book "Singularities of complex hypersurfaces". For a shorter read with lots of more modern references, here is a short introduction by Dimca (math.unice.fr/~dimca/sing.pdf). I should mention that he works in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and looks at the complement of a curve there, but he also gives a reference on p.3 to a part of his book "Sheaves in topology" which discusses the difference.